# Why am I having the jquery error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm having an error - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. It is written in a jQuery custom plugin code. Can anybody help ? returnin the funtion body works neither

```js
(function ($) {
  $.fn.moveAnimate = function () {
    $(".move").animate(
      {
        position: "absolute",
        left: "150px"
      },
      1000
    );
  };
});
```

Comment: You should call the IIFE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Comment: why would the plugin code be hard coded to a selector? seems like a bad usage of jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're attempting to use jQuery's animate method directly inside the plugin definition. To define a custom jQuery plugin correctly, you should return a function that will be executed when the plugin is invoked. Also, you should be calling the IIFE:

```
(function ($) {
 $.fn.moveAnimate = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      // Inside this function, "this" refers to each element matched by the selector
      var $element = $(this);

      $element.animate(
        {
          position: "absolute",
          left: "150px"
        },
        1000
      );
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

You can then use it on your selection of elements like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".move").moveAnimate();
});
```